# Does juju helps to build own private cloud?

Tags: juju

Will juju help me to create my own cloud for my organization, we want to create private cloud for my organisation if it helps what are the guidelines that we need to got through?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is one of the things that Juju (and MAAS) can help you do. If you have your own servers and wish to turn those in to a private cloud you can do one of two things at the moment with Juju.

You can just install MAAS on those servers. MAAS, Metal as a Service, is a Canonical tool to allow you to treat "metal" (bare servers, or VMs) as a Cloud. After you've done so, you have a "cloud". While it's not a traditional cloud you can use Juju to drive your servers.

If you're looking for a more traditional "private cloud", you can use your MAAS+Juju setup to deploy OpenStack. OpenStack is available as Juju charms. So once you've setup MAAS and Juju you can use Juju to deploy all the OpenStack charms. Once deployed you've now got MAAS, using Juju you've deployed another cloud on top of that (OpenStack). At this point you can walk away and use OpenStack as a cloud or configure Juju to now use that new OpenStack service to deploy other Juju charms.